# Texture only shown on one side, the other side is the white default shader

Tags: texturing

[image]

It's .abc animated mesh exported from Marvelous Designer but without any thickness. When I put the texture on it, it only has the front side showing the desired texture, the back side is the default white shader. How can I make both sides show the same texture?

Comment: Hello could you please share the object itself? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I appreciate it mate. Heck! Problem solved. In case other people had a similar issue later I'll leave my solution here. Turns out the shader is a mixed shader and has a translucent shader connected to it and it is set to pure white... Just connect the painted texture to the translucent shader and it's all good!